# Prevent wxScrolledWindow from scrolling when proportion is 0

Tags: c++, user-interface, layout, wxwidgets

I am trying to layout my wxWidgets window.

I have a vertical `wxBoxSizer` with a panel, `proportion = 1`, and a `wxScrolledWindow`, `proportion = 0`. I want the `wxScrolledWindow`'s vertical height to be large enough to contain the `wxButton`s inside it, which are laid out horizontally.

However, with `proportion = 0` a vertical scrollbar appears, even though I do not pass the `wxVSCROLL` flag. I tried settings `proportion = 1` but this meant the `wxScrolledWindow` would be taller than necessary.

Here is an image of the problem, taken from inside wxFormBuilder (the same behaviour occurs in the actual wxWidgets program, where the `wxScrolledWindow` has `proportion = 0`:

[image: The wxScrolledWindow has a vertical scrollbar, which I want to remove.]

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: This is what I want the layout to look like. I made this image by manually settings the proportions, but I want it to occur automatically.]

Please could somebody explain how I could achieve this in C++ (or wxFormBuilder, it doesn't matter); I have glanced through the wxWidgets documentation but I am a novice at GUI libraries in general so assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the vertical scrollbar, just disable it, otherwise the layout code doesn't really know which size is desired for your scrolled window.

Here is something that creates the layout that you want (you can paste it into the minimal sample, at the end of `MyFrame` ctor, to test):

```
auto const sv = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
sv->Add(new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "Button 0"), wxSizerFlags(1).Border());
auto const p = new wxScrolledWindow(this);
p->SetScrollRate(10, 0);
auto const sh = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    sh->Add(new wxButton(p, wxID_ANY, wxString::Format("Button %d", i)), wxSizerFlags().Border());
p->SetSizer(sh);
sv->Add(p, wxSizerFlags().Expand());
SetSizer(sv);
```

Comment: This works, but the horizontal scrollbar seems to sometimes overlap the buttons until I resize the window. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: If you do it dynamically, i.e. not during the window creation, you need to call `Layout()` (during window creation this happens automatically as it's resized to its initial size). If the problem persists, you'd need to reproduce it in the minimal sample to show what exactly are you doing, it's really difficult to say anything more otherwise.

Comment: Well, the flag `wxALWAYS_SHOW_SB` seems to fix it. Thanks for the help.